# Greatest Integer Function Linear Equality.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Number of natural numbers satisfying the equation $$\left[\dfrac{x}{49}\right]=\left[\dfrac{x}{51}\right]$$ (where $[\cdot]$ denotes Greatest Integer Function)?

Comment: $625$ (if $0$ is considered natural; fairly simple problem - what are your efforts?)

Comment: Hint: $51 \cdot 49=2499$. So for any $x \in \Bbb{N}$,we can write $x=2499q+r$, for some $q \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $0 \leq r <2499$.

Answer (score 1):

Since

$\dfrac{x}{49}-1<\left[\dfrac{x}{49}\right]\leq \dfrac{x}{49}$

$\dfrac{x}{51}-1<\left[\dfrac{x}{51}\right]\leq \dfrac{x}{51}$

we have $$\dfrac{x}{49}-1< \dfrac{x}{51}\implies x<{49\cdot 51\over 2}\implies x\leq 2499$$ and
$$\dfrac{x}{51}-1< \dfrac{x}{49}\implies x>-{49\cdot 51\over 2}\implies x\geq -2499$$

So there is $2499$ natural solution to this equation. (I don't consider $0$ as natural.)

Comment: But the answer given is $624$ I did by this process only but failed to match with the answers.